Strategies for Achieving Decoupling Between API Methods and User Interfaces
What are the proven strategies for achieving decoupling between API methods and user interfaces?
I'm working on creating a REST API service for the application. And I noticed that my API methods are strongly coupled with the user interface.
Let's assume that I have this simple entity in my app
public class User{
    private String username;
    private List<String> roles;
    private Set<String> permissions;
}

Now let's have a look at the user interface.

There are two pages in the user interface, one allows an admin to create a user by specifying his username and roles. Another page allows an admin to issue permissions.
This means that I have to create two API methods, one to create a user and assign roles. And another one for issuing permissions.
public class UserService{
    public User createUser(User user){
        // save user to db
        // assign roles;
    }
    
    public User assignPermissions(Integer userId, List<String> permissions){
        // find user from db
        // assign permissions
    }
}

Why should I strictly follow the UI? In my opinion, it is more logical to create three API methods, one for creating a user, another for assigning roles and the last for issuing permits.
So, how can I achieve this decoupling?

That's roughly "Architecture" and way too broad to really answer in any definitive way. There are many approaches and opinions. Yes, you don't need to follow the UI, you do however need to design both parts in a way that they work together, and there are benefits to design according to the needs of your app because that's usually "the product"


Why should I strictly follow the UI? In my opinion, it is more logical to create three API methods [...]

Your API should indeed not reflect the UI, which would be an inverted dependency to begin with.  An API ideally exposes methods that reflect the relevant actions of some (functional) workflow.  The UI leverages the API but can regroup and reshape the "low-level" actions, up to the wizards.
A special consideration about API methods for the retrieval/search of data:  One might envision an API that makes any query possible, but a naive approach to that simply ends up reinventing SQL or equivalent as a DSL for the user.  If just offering a set of parameterized queries is not enough (and only requirements can justify that), the next level would be (something like) GraphQL.


In my opinion, it is more logical to create three API methods, one for creating a user, another for assigning roles and the last for issuing permits.

You are on the right path in thinking like this.
There may be some issue with how your UI is designed. Typically User has role(s) and Role has permission(s). So Roles/Permissions need to be managed separately in UI and once created, the role can be assigned to a user in a separate UI. My answer is based on the assumption that this rule applies to your problem space as well.

In my view, you should think purely in terms of the Domain when designing APIs and should never couple it with UI at all. Domain is the problem space you are creating software for.
APIs can be a product in themselves. Some companies provides just APIs and consumers build their own UI. Imagine creating a custom Twitter client using Twitter apis.
So, I would think purely in terms of the domain and how to enable capabilities of the domain via APIs.

How to apply domain thinking to design APIs without any UI?
- Define Entities
- Define Relationships (how Entities are related with each other)
- Enable Capabilitiies

How to do that in your use case?
Define Entities
- User
    - Is it meaningful in your domain to have a user without roles and permissions?
    - Can they do anything without roles and permissions in your domain?

- Role
    - What kind of roles are possible in your domain?
    - Is it possible for a user to have multiple roles?
    - Is it possible to have a role without any permission in your domain?
    - What kind of permissions are possible in your domain?

Define Relationships
- User has array(Role)
- Role has set(Permission)
- Your model should resemble this structure unlike what you have mentioned above.

public class User {
    private UUID id; //generated by service at the time of creating a User and returned in api response
    private String username;
    private List<String> roleIds;
}

public class Role {
    private UUID id; //generated by service at the time of creating a Role and returned in api response
    private String name
    private Set<String> permissions
}

Enable Capabilities
- Develop POST API for creating a Role. Each role should have a unique id.
- Develop PATCH API for updating an existing Role permissions by taking roleId as input.
- Develop POST API for creating a User with List<String> roleIds
- Develop PATCH API for updating an existing Users roleIds by taking userId as input

